# Traffic from raw C socket to UDP server shows up in tcpdump but server doesn't receive/print out data

Tags: c, sockets, server, network-programming, client

I have been meaning to learn C raw sockets, so I have programmed a UDP server using DGRAM sockets and a client using raw sockets. My goal is to create a UDP packet from scratch and to send it over the raw socket to the UDP socket.
I can run both the client and the server with no compiler errors or warnings, and the server seems to receive data properly, as it can print out the packets received using the command `netcat -u 172.18.181.100 3333` for example.
However, when sending packets from my client, the server doesn't seem to receive anything, despite the relevant traffic actually showing up in tcpdump or wireshark. The packets i send using the client don't seem to contain errors as they aren't flagged by wireshark in any way.

Here is server.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1500

int main(void)
{
    int result;

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo* server_infos;
    struct addrinfo* cursor;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    //setting hints
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    getaddrinfo("172.18.100.181", "3333", &hints, &server_infos);

    int udpsocket_fd;
    for(cursor = server_infos; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->ai_next)
    {
        udpsocket_fd = socket(cursor->ai_family, cursor->ai_socktype, cursor->ai_protocol);
        if(udpsocket_fd == -1)
            continue;
        result = bind(udpsocket_fd, cursor->ai_addr, cursor->ai_addrlen);
        if(result == 0)
            break;
    }
    if(cursor == NULL)
    {
        printf("No suitable interface\n");
        exit(1);
    }
   
    while(1)
    {
        char buffer[BUFSIZE];
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
        result = recvfrom(udpsocket_fd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);
        for(int i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++)
        {
            if(i % 16 == 0)
                printf("\n");
            printf("%c ", buffer[i]);
        }
    }

return 0; 
}
```

And here is client.c :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>

#define PACKET_BUFFER 1024
#define UDP 17

unsigned short ip_checksum(struct iphdr* ip_header, int ip_header_length)
{
    short* cursor = (short*) ip_header;
    int checksum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ip_header_length/2; i++)
    {
        checksum += htons(cursor[i]);
        checksum = (checksum & 0x0000ffff) + (checksum >> 16);
    }

return (unsigned short) (~checksum);
}

int main(void)
{   
    int result;
    int rawsocket_fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
 
    char packet[PACKET_BUFFER];
    memset(packet, 0, PACKET_BUFFER);

    //ethernet header
    struct ethhdr* ethernet_header = (struct ethhdr*) packet;
    //source mac
    ethernet_header->h_source[0] = 0x00;
    ethernet_header->h_source[1] = 0x15;
    ethernet_header->h_source[2] = 0x5d;
    ethernet_header->h_source[3] = 0x6c;
    ethernet_header->h_source[4] = 0xae;
    ethernet_header->h_source[5] = 0x2b;
    //dest mac
    ethernet_header->h_dest[0] = 0x00;
    ethernet_header->h_dest[1] = 0x15;
    ethernet_header->h_dest[2] = 0x5d;
    ethernet_header->h_dest[3] = 0x6c;
    ethernet_header->h_dest[4] = 0xae;
    ethernet_header->h_dest[5] = 0x2b;
    //protocol
    ethernet_header->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_IP);

    //ip header
    struct iphdr* ip_header = (struct iphdr*) (ethernet_header + 1);
    ip_header->version = 4;
    char ip_saddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = "172.18.100.181";
    char ip_daddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = "172.18.100.181";
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_saddr, &(ip_header->saddr));
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_daddr, &(ip_header->daddr));
    ip_header->ihl = 5;
    ip_header->protocol = UDP;
    ip_header->ttl = 64;
    ip_header->tos = 16;
    ip_header->id = htons(1212);
    ip_header->check = ip_checksum(ip_header, 20);

    //udp header
    struct udphdr* udp_header = (struct udphdr*) (ip_header + 1);
    udp_header->source = htons(12001);
    udp_header->dest = htons(3333);
    udp_header->check = 0;

    //raw data (payload)
    char* raw_data = (char*) (udp_header + 1);
    unsigned short raw_data_length = 0;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x61;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x62;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x63;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x64;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x65;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x66;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x67;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x68;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x69;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x6a;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x6b;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x6c;
    raw_data[raw_data_length++] = 0x6d;

    //filling missing fields
    ip_header->tot_len = htons(raw_data - (char*) ip_header + raw_data_length);
    udp_header->len = htons(raw_data - (char*) udp_header + raw_data_length);

    unsigned short packet_total_len = raw_data + raw_data_length - packet;

    //sockaddr_ll to specify destination mac/interface index/other informations, necessary to use sendto
    struct sockaddr_ll server_address_ll;
    //index of interface to send to
    server_address_ll.sll_ifindex = 2;
    //length of destination mac address 
    server_address_ll.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
    //Setting destination mac address in 
    server_address_ll.sll_addr[0] = 0x00;
    server_address_ll.sll_addr[1] = 0x15;
    server_address_ll.sll_addr[2] = 0x5d;
    server_address_ll.sll_addr[3] = 0x6c;
    server_address_ll.sll_addr[4] = 0xae;
    server_address_ll.sll_addr[5] = 0x2b;

    result = sendto(rawsocket_fd, packet, packet_total_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address_ll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    if(result == -1)
    {
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

And here are captures from the traffic that shows up in tcpdump and wireshark :

[tcpdump traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chwPD.png)
[wireshark traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYpDZ.png)

I don't really understand what i'm doing wrong, i'd appreciate any help, thanks !

Tried sending packets from a client using raw sockets to a server using udp sockets, udp server doesn't seem to receive the traffic even though the traffic shows up in wireshark or tcpdump. Tried prompting the server with netcat and tftp, and it seems to work fine, despite this it still doesn't receive traffic from my client program.

Comment: Wireshark by default does not check the IP header checksum. You should enable that feature and at least make sure the checksums are correct.

Comment: Thank you, i've enabled the checksum verification and it was faulty as you've said. In my code i was calculating the checksum before filling out the tot_len field of the ip header, which caused it to calculate the wrong value. However, i've fixed the problem, and my checksum now appears as correct, but my server still doesn't print out any data.

Comment: I was wondering if the problem had anything to do with wireshark displaying the protocol as LLC, but i changed the client port to 8888, wireshark now displays the protocol as being UDP, and nothing has changed regarding the server not receiving data from the client.

Comment: Wireshark is showing the source IP address as `0.0.0.0` which is invalid.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Thanks, i've changed the code up a bit and this is how my packets look like now : [wireshark packets](https://www.imgur.com/a/RwxT0x1) The packet with the invalid udp checksum is the netcat packet, the other is my client packet. Virtually the only difference aside from the checksum and the udp ports is the packet type from wireshark's linux cooked capture packet. I don't understand why they are different and i suspect that this where the problem resides. I've tried to look up wireshark's source code to make sense of it but i don't really get it.